# How to pass data from a selected item to another component in angular 2

Tags: angular, components

I'll be simple:
I have a component named step1.component.ts wich template has a ngFor and each item is selectable simple (selectable is a directive), so I need show the selected item info in the next component named step2.component.ts. I've searched a lot but I don't know how to make it.

**step1.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let card of card.cardItem" class="collection-row selectable" selectableSimple>
  <th class="center-align"><img src="{{card.logo}}" alt=""></th>
  <th>{{card.denomination}}</th>
  <th>{{card.idNumber}}</th>
  <th>{{card.arsBalance | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}</th>
  <th>{{card.usdBalance | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}</th>
  <th>{{card.dueDate | date}}</th>
</tr>
```

**step1.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'
import {DummiesService} from '../../services/dummies.service';
import {Card} from '../../models/card.model';
import {ActionCustom} from '../../component/action/actionCustom.component';
import {CollectionCustom} from '../../component/collection/collection.component'

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'step1.component.html',
  directives: [ActionCustom],
  providers: [DummiesService, CollectionCustom]
})

export class Step1{
  cards: Card[];

  constructor(protected dummiesService:DummiesService){
    this.cards=dummiesService.getCards();
  }
}
```

**selectableSimple.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $:any;

@Directive({ 
  selector: '[selectableSimple]' 
})

export class SelectableSimple implements AfterViewInit{

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  $('.collection-row').click(function(){
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    })
  };

}
```

Comment: How are step 1 and step2 related? Are they both children of the same parent? If not use a shared service. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: In step1, when you select a option an press the "continue" button, it redirects (using angular routing) to step2 component. I think they are not children

Comment: If you use the router, then you can only use a shared service.

Comment: Okay, but I don't know how to make to share this service and how to display the shared data in de step2

Comment: And, there is another way to navigate through views without using routin, I mean like ngSwitch (I proofed but doesn't work)?

Comment: See the link in my first comment.